# Why does the width property affect the flex-item even though flex-basis is set?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have tried a little bit with **flex-box** and I don't understand something about it. Until now I thought that the value of the **width** property of a **flex-box** item doesn't matter as long as the **flex-basis** is set. I found this claim also in [this Blog](https://mastery.games/post/the-difference-between-width-and-flex-basis/). But if I remove the **width** property of the **div** element, the result changes. Why? What exactly happens here?

[image: flex-basis: 40px; and width: 40px; set]
*flex-basis: 40px;* and *width: 40px;* of div element set

[image: flex-basis: 40px; and width: 40px; is not set]
*flex-basis: 40px;* and *width: 40px;* of div element **not** set

I also created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4hpL9xd/47/).

### *flex-basis: 40px;* and *width: 40px;* of div element set:

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

section
{
    display: inline-block;
}

ol
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
    background-color: gray;
}

li
{
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

a
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

div /* Icon Placeholder */
{
    flex-basis: 40px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    
    background-color: red;
}

p
{
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>Glue the sheet to the dark blue background.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>It's easy to tell the depth of a well.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>Rice is often served in round bowls.</p></a></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

### *flex-basis: 40px;* and *width: 40px;* of div element not set:

```css
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

section
{
    display: inline-block;
}

ol
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    
    background-color: gray;
}

li
{
    flex-basis: auto;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    
    background-color: greenyellow;
}

a
{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

div /* Icon Placeholder */
{
    flex-basis: 40px;
    flex-grow: 0;
    flex-shrink: 0;

    height: 40px;
    
    background-color: red;
}

p
{
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <ol>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>The birch canoe slid on the smooth planks.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>Glue the sheet to the dark blue background.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>It's easy to tell the depth of a well.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>These days a chicken leg is a rare dish.</p></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><div></div><p>Rice is often served in round bowls.</p></a></li>
    </ol>
</section>
```

Comment: refer this https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-the-differences-between-flex-basis-and-width-in-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

You have set `flex-direction: row;` on the containing anchor element which means that the `flex-basis` will be the width of the row.

You have set the `flex-basis` as well as the width on the `div` element inside that parent element.
Note that changing the width on those div elements does not change the width of the div, which you see in your screenshot as well. It says the expected 40px, because you also set `flex-grow` to 0. A handy shorthand is btw `flex: [grow] [shrink] [basis]`.

So what is happening now: All parent elements of your div with the basis are growing, because they have `width: auto;` by default, this affects the containing `a` element as well as the `li`.
In return, the neighbouring element of the div, the `p` with a green background, also fills its parent container, because it has no flex-basis and `width: auto` as well.

So why is this happening?
You can see that when you add e.g. 10px of width to your div, that the container grows 10px accordingly and as a block element the p tag tags up the new remaining space.
This is a nested flex, which is known to have some bugs - I am not sure this is one of them or expected behavior, but the parent element grows based on the width that you set and not on the actual it takes up in the dom or the flex-basis.

As a general hint: Maybe look into css grid for more complex, nested layouts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that flex-basis defines the size along the major axis. In this case with flex-direction: row it would be the horizontal width, so the width property.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis

Comment: Sorry, maybe I missed the issue. I will look at it later.

Comment: I was a bit in a hurry when I wrote the original answer and it was not really helpful. I updated it now and I hope it is a bite more accurate, but I am not sure if I have gotten everything this time, because you have quite a bit of different flex boxes going on. As this has been closed as a duplicate (wrongfully I think), let me know if thats still not what you are asking and consider changing your vote ;)